# How to make a Sprite move when comes into contact with another object

Tags: swift, sprite

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, please let me know if I am doing something wrong. My task is simple, I want to send the sprite moving at a random distance when it comes into contact with the tennis racker / object. I need help with the second part of my task. Can anyone please help me? I am relatively new to Swift, so please keep that in mind.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var tennisRacket: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var moveRacket: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UILabel!


var tennisScene = SKScene()
var tennisBallSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "tennisball")



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // hide or show elements

    playButton.hidden = false
    tennisRacket.hidden = true
    moveRacket.hidden = true
    scoreLabel.hidden = true
    scoreText.hidden = true
    tennisBallSprite.hidden = true

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}


@IBAction func playPressed(sender: UIButton) {


    playButton.hidden = true
    tennisRacket.hidden = false
    moveRacket.hidden = false
    tennisBallSprite.hidden = false


    tennisBallSprite.position = CGPointZero
    tennisBallSprite.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    tennisBallSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    tennisBallSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    tennisScene.addChild(tennisBallSprite)

}



@IBAction func hitBall(sender: UIButton) {





    self.tennisRacket.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((-15 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)



    delay(1/5) {

        self.tennisRacket.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

We like to try and make it so users don't have to open any links to understand the question, to make the site more friendly to people on any device (ie mobile).

Please post relevant snippets of code in your question, instead of using a pastebin.

It might be helpful to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve